# I got an error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Tags: vb.net

This is my code behind

```
Private Property ListEmployee As List(Of Employee)
    Get
        Return Session(Me.GetType.Name)
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As List(Of Employee))
        Session(Me.GetType.Name) = value
    End Set
End Property
Private ReadOnly Property objEmployee As Employee
    Get
        Dim obj As New Employee
        obj.User_ID = txtUserID.Text.Trim
        obj.Name = txtName.Text.Trim
        obj.Position = txtPosition.Text.Trim
        Return obj
    End Get
End Property
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

End Sub
Protected Sub btnAddtoTable_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAddtoTable.Click
    ListEmployee.Add(objEmployee) 'error at here
    gvResult.DataSource = ListEmployee
    gvResult.DataBind()
End Sub
```

End Class

i try to add data as (Class Employee) into ListEmployee as (List of Employee) and then display on gridview but i got an error.

Comment: Have you tried stepping into your code to see what the values for `ListEmployee` and `objEmployee` are?  Most likely `ListEmployee` is not in `Session`.

Comment: ListEmployee ==> value = count = 0 (Error No children available)         objEmployee  ==> has value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is best to breakpoint and split the function up to see where the fault lies but looking at your code I am pretty sure the problem is in the ListEmployee object. `ListEmployee.Add()` will get a reference to the ListEmplyee object and you are not checking if this object actually exists yet. You need to do some data validation checking in both the `ListEmployee` property and the `objEmployee`, I will do it in the `ListEmployee` for you here:

```
Private Property ListEmployee As List(Of Employee)
Get
    If Not IsNothing(Session(Me.GetType.Name)) Then
       Return Session(Me.GetType.Name)
    Else
       Dim le as New List(Of Employee)
       le.add(objEmployee)
       Session(Me.GetType.Name) = le
       Return le
    End If
End Get
Set(ByVal value As List(Of Employee))
    Session(Me.GetType.Name) = value
End Set
End Property
```

Comment: Thanks Mr.Moore. The error was solved but i don't get any data in my gridview.

Comment: Yes that would be correct. What is happening is that you are trying to load data from `Session(Me.GetType.Name)` but there is nothing there. You are not loading data into the session object. To solve this problem you need to work out why there is no data in `Session(Me.GetType.Name)`. Are you sure you have loaded it?

Comment: Do you have any idea How do i add objEmployee into  ListEmployee ==>Session(Me.GetType.Name)

Comment: If I understand you want to create a new instance of objEmployee, then add this to ListEmployee and then put that inside Session(Me.GetType.Name). Is that correct?

Comment: yes and then Bind it into Gridview.

Comment: I have modifed my answer. It is not advised to put complex objects in the session memory but there it is anyway.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mr.Moore. You are genius.